# Weekday and Workday Formula gives Value Error in terms of calculating actual due dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on calculating our work completion dates, and I want to think I have a pretty good understanding of IF statements, but I can't seem to figure this one out at all.

So we have three products: policy, quotes and rating, and they each have their own service times/dates process.
- If a policy is requested before 4 pm, then it has to be completed the same day, otherwise if it comes in after 4:00 pm, then you have till 11:59 the next day.
- With quotes you have 48 hours to complete them, and with rating you have 7 days.

I also have a lookup sheet which references company holidays, and I decided to use workday function because some services get in on Fridays, and we are only count weekdays when calculating our due dates. I have also attached my formula in text below, do you guys think that I'm messing up in terms of how I am using both (OR) and (AND) functions to nest the IF statement?

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(IF(A2="Quote",D2+2,IF(A2="Rating",Q2+7,"")))=1,WEEKDAY(IF(A2="Quote",D2+2,IF(A2="Rating",D2+7,""))=7),
IF(A2="Quote",D2+2,IF(A2="Rating",D2+7,""))+2,
IF(A2="Quote",D2+2,IF(A2="Rating",D2+7,""))),
IF(OR(A2="Policy",HOUR(C2<=16),INT(C2)+TIME(23,59,0)),
IF(OR(A2="Policy",HOUR(C2)>16),WORKDAY(D2,1,Lookup!$M$2:$M$20)+TIME(23,59,0),"ERROR"))
```

[Photo of work and columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR5Nj.png)

Comment: Using the Formula Ribbon > Evaluate Formula should help you debug this. For starters, when the `IF`  formulas within a `WEEKDAY` formula resolve to an empty string, you've already got an error. I.e. you can't do `=WEEKDAY("")`.

Comment: So to be clear, for ratings if today is Monday the 1st then you have until Wednesday the 10th to complete?

Comment: And do any requests come in on a weekend?

Comment: And is 11:59 am or pm?

Comment: I see there are 22 "(" but only 21 ")" in your syntax, try to check the parenthesis placements. ( :

Comment: Sorry 11:59 pm!

Comment: @p._phidot_ ,i will check it, these parenthesis are a pain!

Comment: When you say *If a policy is requested before 4 pm, then it has to be completed the same day*, is the due date effectively 1 second before midnight that day? And will the start date ever fall on a weekend?

Comment: @roberth you can use notepad++ to 'detect' and trace the missing ones.  ( It's my favorite tool.., just recommended it coz it works for me.)  please share your 'corrected' code to proceed..  (  :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your requirements correctly, then you should be able to use `=IF(A2="Policy",IF(HOUR(C2)<16,D2,WORKDAY(D2,1)), WORKDAY(D2,IF(A2="Quote",1,IF(A2="Rating",7,0))))`

That just returns a date. If you want it to return a datetime, then use this:

`=IF(A2="Policy",IF(HOUR(C2)<16,D2+1,WORKDAY(D2,1)+1)-1/1440,  WORKDAY(D2,IF(A2="Quote",1,IF(A2="Rating",7,0)))+TIME(HOUR(C2),MINUTE([StartTime]),0))`

...which returns this:

[image]

The Due By column has a custom number format applied of `mmmm d, yyyy h:mm AM/PM`

Comment: yes I'd need datetime, which is why I tried to also use the datevalue function, with text function embedded in there, but that didn't work

Comment: I've amended my answer to reflect my current understanding of your requirements. These might be incorrect: You have yet to answer some of my questions in the comments section below your question, and your answers might change my understanding.

Comment: Sorry, missed your previous comment, you were right to understand that if it's Monday the 1st, then you'd have till the 10th. Also wow, i had a similar formula to your's initially, but it seems I really over complicated it. It makes sense looking at it, but I will plug it in and let you know! Thank you.

Comment: can i ask you what's the reasoning behind using -1/1440 in the function you provided? (WORKDAY(D2,1)+1)-1/1440). Also, the start date shouldn't fall on the weekend, but weirder things have happened, and yes the due date is effectively 1 sec before midnight, but I just had it as 11:59:00. instead of 11:59:59

Comment: There's 1440 minutes in a day. So what i'm doing is saying *"Give me the due date, add one day, and then subtract one minute to take us back just before midnight on the due day"*. Does the formula do what you want?

Comment: It gave me date values that were rounded down, like for instance a due date of 5:21 would show up as 5:00 pm.

Comment: Ah, sorry 'bout that. Have amended formula.

Comment: I will try that out too and see if it gives me anything different than what I currently have. @Jeffreyweir, thanks for all your help with this. I do appreciate it. But, one last question...how would that formula take into account company holidays? Or does the workday function already have built in holiday thing?

Comment: For instance, can i add an If statement with a holiday lookup reference into your formula?

Comment: Yes, the WORKDAY function has an optional 3rd argument that you can point at a range that contains holidays. Please mark my answer as accepted if it solves your issue.

Comment: Is it possible to reference a holiday time frame that I have in another worksheet to this function? If so, where would I place it? =IF(OR(WEEKDAY(IF(A2="Quote",D2+(1),IF(A2="Policy",D2+(2),IF(A2="Rating",D2+(1/3),""))))=1,WEEKDAY(IF(A2="Quote",D2+(1),IF(A2="Policy",D2+(2),IF(A2="Rating",D2+(1/3),"")))=7),IF(A2="Quote",D2+(1),IF(A2="Policy",D2+(2),IF(A2="Rating",D2+(1/3),""))))+2,IF(A2="Quote",D2+(1),IF(A2="Policy",D2+(2),IF(A2="Rating",D2+(1/3),""))))